# Flutter: in-app product shows app name next to product name

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

This is what I have on my console:

[image]

but I get also my app name next to the product name:

[image]

`(My Rents)`

I could just remove it from the string but I have my app name translated to some languages and I'd like to know if it's possible to get it without the app name

Comment: what does it say on the stores for The title of the product?

Comment: the tile is `My Rents`

Comment: @Dani did you solve this?

Comment: it's looking alright now  but I think I did nothing. Maybe this was a bug fixed at some point